# Include a External library in my Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, gson

When i run my project i get this error:
[image]

Why i get this?

I include this in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.
I understood the kind of problem but in maven I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @DavideBorrello Then ask *that* question. The question you asked now is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: If you want more help, you need to share the Maven script that built the jar, and any relevant dependencies. Most likely you just need to add the Gson jar to the classpath when calling `java -jar`

Comment: @jorn i added part of pom.xml

Maybe write <classpath> in the pom isn't efficient way.

Comment: This actually sounds more like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594